# Passing asyncio loop by argument or using default asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio in my application and i'm a litte bit confused about passing the *event loop* as argument.

You've three possibilities when writing a function/method using the *event loop*:

- Pass the asyncio *event loop* as argument
- Don't use an argument for the *event loop* and use `asyncio.get_event_loop()`
- Make it optional to pass the *event loop* as argument. If it is not passed, use `asyncio.get_event_loop()`

It seems that the last case is used most of the time but even in the asyncio api the usage is inconsistent. As I don't indent to use two seperated *event loops* what speaks against just using `asyncio.get_event_loop()` where needed?

What's the best way to go?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "passing the event loop as argument"? Passing the event loop from where to where? This is a bit application specific rather than a generic question (depending on how the application is using the event loop the answer might vary).

Comment: `asyncio.get_event_loop()` returns an event loop, you can change it with `asyncio.set_event_loop()`. This will `get/set` the event loop on the `_event_loop_policy`, a global variable in the `asyncio` module. This is an easy way to share the eventloop in the application without a need to pass it around. So if you want to avoid having 2 separate event loops around, you may register the one event loop you've got in this global variable by `set_event_loop()`.

Comment: @farzad: Typically my application starts with `loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()`. Then I'm setting up the asynchronous stuff (coroutines, async servers, ...) and my own functions where I've got this question about passing the loop argument. When everything is set up, I run `loop.run_forever()`.

Comment: Related: [asyncio-doc#13](https://github.com/asyncio-doc/asyncio-doc/pull/13)

Comment: This is a great question, hope some more light can be shed on this by someone in the know...

Comment: Here is a good read on the topic: [getting in touch with your eventloop](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#getting-in-touch-with-your-event-loop)  (long, but worth starting from the top). Basically: If you're only every going to use one loop, it doesn't matter. From python 3.6, it mostly doesn't matter even if you do.

Comment: Finally, [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/async-sig/2016-November/000171.html) mail thread spawned from the above mentioned blog post, answers your question: go for option 2 (after python 3.6)

Comment: @ttyridal Thank you for your comment. I've got good experience with option 2 and now always work that way. Would you consider to write your comment as answer? I would consider your comment as correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good (as in praised by Guido van Rossum) blog post discussing this is [Some thoughts on asynchronous API design in a post-async/await world](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#getting-in-touch-with-your-event-loop). With a follow up discussion from python core developers [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/async-sig/2016-November/000171.html).

TLDR;

If you're only using one event loop, it doesn't matter.

If you're managing multiple loops, **and have python >= 3.6** it mostly doesn't matter: Do not use argument and use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` where needed, it will give you the correct loop.

Comment: It took me a while to verify that Guido was onboard with this. This message was useful for that: 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-tulip/yF9C-rFpiKk/tk5oA3GLHAAJ

Comment: `get_event_loop` is now deprecated since Python 3.12 https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop